# Thread / Timer count limit in BlackBerry OS5-7

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, java-me

How many Threads/Timer's can a BlackBerry application have live at any given time?

I'm assuming here that Timer objects are not handled special by the OS - they simply use Thread.sleep or some such to get them selves "scheduled".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16 threads per application, and there's also a global limit of 128 threads in the device. If you exceed any of these limits, a TooManyThreadsError will be thrown.

About the `Timers`, each one has a background thread. From the [Timer class javadoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/util/Timer.html):

> *Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially.*

Comment: Which also just made me realize that you can schedule multiple TimerTask object's per Timer. Occupational blindness.... but thanks for the short, sweet and accurate answer. Cheers!